# Unable to retrieve service key for ServicePrincipal account

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

We are getting an error when trying to authenticate to the AzureRM PS cmdlets using a Service Principal on a remote machine. However, the commands do work locally. We have tried Azure PowerShell versions 1.4 and 2.1 (latest) with no success. We also see the same behavior when executing the PS commands through a remote PSEXEC call, which seems to rule out an issue with PowerShell Remoting.

This is the command we are trying:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [***REMOTEMACHINENAME***] {$creds = Get-Credential -Credential (New-Object pscredential("[***AccountIdRemoved***]",("[***ClientSecretRemoved***]" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)));Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds -TenantId "[***TenantIdRemoved***]" -ServicePrincipal | Out-String;Get-AzureRmKeyVault | Out-String}
```

This is the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Add-AzureAccount to set up your Azure credentials. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Unable to retrieve service key for ServicePrincipal account [***AccountIdRemoved***]. Please log in again to supply the credentials for this service principal. In PowerShell, execute Login-AzureRMAccount for Azure Resource Manager cmdlets or Add-AzureAccount for service management cmdlets.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ServicePrincipalTokenProvider.RenewWithSecret(AdalConfiguration config, String appId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ServicePrincipalTokenProvider.GetAccessToken(AdalConfiguration config, ShowDialog promptBehavior, String u
serId, SecureString password, AccountType credentialType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate(AzureAccount account, AzureEnvironment environment, String te
nant, SecureString password, ShowDialog promptBehavior, TokenCache tokenCache, Endpoint resourceId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.AuthenticationFactory.GetSubscriptionCloudCredentials(AzureContext context, Endpoint targetEndpo
int)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.AuthenticationFactory.GetSubscriptionCloudCredentials(AzureContext context, Endpoint targetEndpo
int)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Components.ResourceManagerClientHelper.GetResourceManagerClient(AzureContext context, Dictionary`2 cmdle
tHeaderValues)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Components.ApiVersionHelper.GetApiVersionsForResourceType(AzureContext context, String providerNamespace
, String resourceType, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Dictionary`2 cmdletHeaderValues)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Components.ApiVersionHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7.<DetermineApiVersion>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Components.ApiVersionHelper.ApiVersionCache.AddOrGetExisting(String cacheKey, Func`1 getFreshData)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Components.ApiVersionHelper.DetermineApiVersion(AzureContext context, String providerNamespace, String r
esourceType, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nullable`1 pre, Dictionary`2 cmdletHeaderValues)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.ResourceManagerCmdletBase.DetermineApiVersion(String providerNamespace, String resourceTy
pe, Nullable`1 pre)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet.<ListResourcesInSubscription>d__2c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet.<GetResources>d__c.MoveNext()
```